# Is my understanding about tensorflow retracing correct?

Tags: tensorflow

[tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function) give this example

```
def train_one_step():
  pass

@tf.function
def train(num_steps):
  print("Tracing with num_steps = ", num_steps)
  tf.print("Executing with num_steps = ", num_steps)
  for _ in tf.range(num_steps):
    train_one_step()

print("Retracing occurs for different Python arguments.")
train(num_steps=10)
train(num_steps=20)

print()
print("Traces are reused for Tensor arguments.")
train(num_steps=tf.constant(10))
train(num_steps=tf.constant(20))
```

Here is the output

```
Retracing occurs for different Python arguments.
Tracing with num_steps =  10
Executing with num_steps =  10
Tracing with num_steps =  20
Executing with num_steps =  20

Traces are reused for Tensor arguments.
Tracing with num_steps =  Tensor("num_steps:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
Executing with num_steps =  10
Executing with num_steps =  20
```

I guess I understand the first part where `train(num_steps)` is defined as a `Function` object. `train(num_steps=10)` and `train(num_steps=20)` use different Python values and result in retracing.

In the second part, `train(num_steps=tf.constant(10))` and `train(num_steps=tf.constant(20))` cause reusing Traces where `print("Tracing with num_steps = ", num_steps)` runs normally while the parameter part `num_steps=tf.constant(10)` is captured by the tf.Graph and does not run in the tracing stage.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorating your function with `tf.function` tells `tensorflow` to generate a computational graph out of it. By default a new graph is generated when you pass a tensor with new shape

this generates new graph as it's the first call:

```py
my_tf_func(tf.constant(10))
```

this does not generate a new graph as the shape of the argument is the same as the input shape of the graph:

```py
my_tf_func(tf.constant(20))
```

this generates new graph as the shape is different:

```py
my_tf_func(tf.constant([10, 20]))
```

When passing python values (not tf.tensors) a new graph is generated everytime a call is made with distinct value. All of these calls generate new graph:

```py
my_tf_func(10) 
my_tf_func(20) 
my_tf_func(30)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What does "out of it" exactly mean?

Comment: the function is traced, from your question, it looks like you got that part figured out so I wasn't very literal.